# Do I have recourse against Air France if they refuse to refund/compensate after wrongful boarding denial?

Tags: international, small-claims-court

I believe I was unfairly denied boarding by Air France and they are refusing to refund my ticket and compensate me for the incurred costs of missing the flight (e.g. missing my connecting flight, hotel accommodations). The problem is that I am a Turkish citizen and can't just go to France to file a small court claim. Do I have any recourse? Can I sue them from Turkey and/or remotely?

For some context:

- I am a Turkish citizen with an ordinary passport.
- My flight trajectory was the following:

  - Depart: Punta Cana, Dominican Republic via Air France
  - Transit: 3 hours transit via Charles de Gaulles, France airport (International zone).
  - Arrival: Istanbul, Turkey via Turkish airlines.
- I was denied boarding in Punta Cana. The reason given then was that "I had not arrived to Dominican Republic with Air France".
- After contacting the Air France complaints department, I was told the actual reason for boarding denial was that I needed a valid transit visa since my onward flight to Istanbul was with another airline (Turkish Airline).
- I contacted the French consulate which confirmed that I did not need a transit visa (they won't even issue one) since I was only stopping for 3 hours through the International zone and that the onward flight did not have to be through the same airline.

Comment: Did you have any checked luggage?  Would you have been able to claim and recheck it without leaving the international zone?

Comment: By the way, you might get more useful practical advice on http://travel.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Was the entire flight booked on one ticket?  Ie both the Air France and Turkish Airlines legs on the same PNR?  If not, then Air France will fight you to the grave, as to them your destination was France, not Turkey, and thus you needed a Schengen visa - without one, if you decided to stay and claim asylum or illegally enter France, Air France would be liable for a large fine.  An onward flight on a separate ticket doesn’t absolve Air France of this obligation, so they refuse to board you.  You aren’t going to get anywhere easily on this even with legal action.

Comment: @NateEldredge, that's not a thing in France.  The US is fairly unique in requiring everyone to clear customs when they arrive, which is why many international travelers avoid hops through the US.

Comment: @ScottDunnington: I know that customs isn't required in Europe when your luggage is checked through.  In this case, because of the change of airline, it may not have been checked through, in which case OP would have had to claim and recheck it.  I am not sure whether that can be done while staying in the international zone - I believe in at least some (non-US) places it can't.